# How to add/insert a rule in the headline and footline

Tags: beamer, formatting

When we use the specified format from beamer, `\documentclass[compress]{beamer}`, how do we add/insert a black line above the headline and under the footline into each slide?

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=secinhead,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=secinhead,bg=black}

\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\tiny}

\usecolortheme[rgb={0,0,0}]{structure}

\useinnertheme{circles}
\newenvironment{proenv}{\only{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=black}}}{}


\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=white,top=white]
```

Comment: Hi, Gonzalo:  If we would like to a black line under the headline and above the footline, how can we modify it?  Thank you...

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: Now, we use:    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{} \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=secinhead,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=secinhead,bg=black}

Comment: No, I mean which beamer theme; are you using the command `\usetheme{Warsaw}` or something similar, perhaps with other theme instead of `Warsaw`?

Comment: \usetheme{Montpellier}

Comment: Any other themes `\useoutertheme`, `\useinnertheme`? Can you please edit your question and add there a little document (like the ones in my answer) showing your current settings?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The code just at the start; is somethink like that what you need?

Comment: Hi, Gonzalo: Thank you so much for your updated answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using

```
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}{}
```

A little example using the relevant settings from the original code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Montpellier}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}
\institute{The Institute}

\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\rule{\paperwidth}{3pt}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The rules I chose in the example are perhaps too thick; instead of `3pt`, select the desired value for the thickness.